# split character column into two to create two separate columns

Tags: r, split

I need to split a character column into two separate columns.

As an example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(city_code=c("New York(NY)","London(LO)","Roma(RO)"))
```

I need an output like:

```
df2 <- data.frame(city=c("New York","London","Roma"), code=c("NY","LO","RO"))
```

Answer (score 2):

In base R:

```
df2 <- data.frame(
    city = sub("\\(.*\\)", "", df1$city_code),
    code = sub(".*\\((.*)\\)", "\\1", df1$city_code))

> df2 
      city code
1 New York   NY
2   London   LO
3     Roma   RO
```

Comment: A variation: `df2 <- data.frame(city = sub("(.*)\\(.*", "\\1", df1$city_code), code = sub(".*\\(([A-Z]{2})\\)", "\\1", df1$city_code))`

Comment: @Jaap I like how you skip `\\)` as it is covered by `.*`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sub` and `strsplit` to create a new table with two columns:

```
do.call(rbind, strsplit(sub(")$", "", df1$city_code), "\\("))
colnames(df2) <- c("city", "code")
df2
#     city       code
#[1,] "New York" "NY"
#[2,] "London"   "LO"
#[3,] "Roma"     "RO"
```

Or using `regexpr` with `regmatches`.

```
df2 <- data.frame(city = regmatches(df1$city_code, regexpr(".*(?=\\()", df1$city_code, perl=TRUE))
 , code = regmatches(df1$city_code, regexpr("(?<=\\().*(?=\\))", df1$city_code, perl=TRUE)))
#      city code
#1 New York   NY
#2   London   LO
#3     Roma   RO
```

Or using `sub` as @Daniel-O and @Jaap have already done.

```
df2 <- data.frame(city = sub("\\(.*", "", df1$city_code)
 , code = sub(".*\\((.+)\\)", "\\1", df1$city_code))
df2
#      city code
#1 New York   NY
#2   London   LO
#3     Roma   RO
```

Or in case the string ends all the time with `(??)` using `substr`.

```
n <- nchar(df1$city_code)
df2 <- data.frame(city = substr(df1$city_code, 1, n-4)
 , code = substr(df1$city_code, n-2, n-1))
df2
#      city code
#1 New York   NY
#2   London   LO
#3     Roma   RO
```

Comment: I was just going to post this :) `setNames(data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(sub('\\)' ,'' ,as.character(df1$city_code)), '\\('))), c('city', 'code'))`. Now that I think it more, it is also better to not escape `(` and simply add `fixed = TRUE`

Answer (score 0):

A `tidyverse` response:

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
  separate(city_code, into = c('city', 'code'), sep = "\\(") %>%
  mutate(code = gsub(')', '', code))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it this way. `\\(` and `\\)` used to separate

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
  separate(city_code, c("city", "code", NA), sep = "\\(|\\)")
```